# i am getting an error while installing npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, node-modules

T[image]his is for a project and i am a beginner in node. this error is not allowing me to install node please do help me with simplified steps. it would really help me.

Comment: Please post text (not images of text), the relevant portion of `package.json`, the relevant portion of the listed log file, and whether or not you actually have git installed. Also, you're not "installing npm", you're trying to install packages *via* npm.

Comment: Do you have git installed on your machine?